# Best way to Implement a MySQL Hash Table?

Tags: mysql, caching, hash, memcached

**Background**

I'm currently developing an online community and I want to store some temporary information in a hash table. Currently this information is being stored in memcached, however, should the memcached service need to be restarted or failed, I would like to resort back to the on disk hash/cache.

**The Question**

What is the most effective method of implementing an on disk Hash or Cache table in MySql? Are there any techniques that I can use to get out of a simple table which will have the following fields:

- Hash Value
- Stored Value
- Expiry Date

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

**Clarity**

- I won't be storing any complex data objects, just simple text strings.
- My current plan is to implement an InnoDB table.
- Any links to articles on a similar topic would be a bonus.

Comment: I think you are a little backwards here.  If you need permanent storage (even if it is "temporary") then you should develop the app using a database first, then use memcached to speed it up.

Comment: @Bob, You raise a good point. Although I'm wanting to build in caching from the start because I think I'll need to do it eventually.

Comment: What are you trying to improve upon in the "simple table" you put forth, especially if the hash value is indexed?

Comment: @Alan. Is there anything I should think about to improve database performance before caching? Datatypes, Storage Engine, Etc?

Comment: @GateKiller: Thinking about performance is good, but maybe you are a bit too eager here. After all, you need but *one* table, three fields, one index - as a backup/persistence solution (you plan on using memcached primarily anyway). I'd simply make a table, do some testing and see how it goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already laid out most of the solution for now: one table, three columns (probably a fourth that's a meaningless integer ID for a primary key), and an index on the hash value column. Ask again later when you have a testable / fixable problem to overcome.

"...premature optimization is the root of all evil" -[Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(computer_science)#cite_note-0)

Comment: "...premature optimization is the root of all evil" I concur!